# JOIN slow nown my Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i update this query, to give me more speed?

Why is the query slower, when I use JOIN?

```
SELECT v.vare_id, 
       LEFT(v.varenavn, 25) as varenavn, 
       v.salgspris, 
       ve.enhed, 
       ve.vare_enhed_id, 
       vt.tilstand, 
       vt.vare_tilstand_id, 
       v.oko_vare, 
       v.varefoto
FROM vare v

JOIN vare_enhed_valg vev
  ON vev.vare_id = v.vare_id

JOIN vare_enhed ve
  ON ve.vare_enhed_id = vev.enhed_id

JOIN vare_tilstand_valg vtv
  ON vtv.vare_id = v.vare_id

JOIN vare_tilstand vt
  ON vt.vare_tilstand_id = vtv.tilstand_id

WHERE v.vare_type_id = 1
  AND v.synlig = "ja"

ORDER BY v.varenavn ASC
```

Comment: Slower - compared to what?

Comment: Add indexes to `v.vare_type_id`, `v.synlig` and `v.varenavn`. You can also try doing the order in php to see if that's slower..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your query, you want an index on: `vare(vare_type_id, v.synlig,  v.varenavn)`.  Other indexes might be appropriate.  Let me assume that the join keys include the primary key of at least one of the tables.